# SharePoint CAML query returns nothing

Tags: development, caml, sharepoint-on-prem, query

I need to find all items from Tasks history (Workflow history) list from SharePoint 2013, but I don't manage to get it exactly right, I have managed to get all items and no items at all.

Any idea, what might be wrong? Since there are items on list with those values:

[image]

Code:

```
     List workflowList = context.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid("{1D356251-D55C-4D7A-97E1-11063B125350}"));

     CamlQuery qryWF = new CamlQuery();
     qryWF.ViewXml =
string.Format(@"<View>
    <Query>
       <Where>
          <And>
             <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='List' />
                <Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value>         
            </Contains>  
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Item' />
                <Value Type='Lookup'>{1}</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>", "aacd3fe2-40a1-4ed3-b5a5-41e00a669848", 76);

      ListItemCollection workflowListItems = workflowList.GetItems(qryWF);
      context.Load(workflowListItems);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Remove <View> and <query> from the CamlQuery.

Comment: Problem was with types, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` and `Item` columns in the Workflow History list has types `Single Line of Text` and `Integer` respectively. Please verify.

So Query will be:

```
<View>
    <Query>
       <Where>
          <And>
             <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='List' />
                <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>         
            </Contains>  
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Item' />
                <Value Type='Integer'>{1}</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```